# Handling "ill-conditioned" system of ODE's with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, series-expansion, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I am currently dealing with a system of coupled ODE's which I would like to solve numerically. I have already implemented the system in Mathematica using `NDSolve`. The system has fixed boundary values (let us say at $-1$ and $1$ the values of the functions are fixed to 0) and one parameter, $k$, which I would like to vary. The system originally includes a Dirac delta, at a certain point $u'$, so my particular implementation tries to find functions at the left and at the right of $u'$ and pastes them appropriately (including the required jump in the derivative).

For small values of $k$ the system is solved properly, however for bigger values, I am getting warnings and messages about the system being "ill-conditioned" or that the "boundary conditions may not be enough to completely specify a solution". I have tried various methods for the solver including `StiffnessSwitching` as well as tweaking the the working precision, the `Accuracy`, `MaxStepSize` and so on.

I actually solve the system in the interval (-.9,.9) in practice and I have noticed that the system can be solved for bigger $k$ if a start making the interval smaller and smaller, however this is not an option for my setting. I believe the instabilities are coming from the boundaries, I should mention they are originally conditions at infinity and I am using a $u=\tanh(x)$ to map $\mathbb{R}$ into $(-1,1)$. Are there any tricks or recommendations on how to handle this phenomena, or alternatives to `NDSolve`?

EDIT:
A toy model of the problem already appears here I believe
$$\delta(u-u') = \left(2u\frac{\partial}{\partial u}-(1-u^2)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial u^2}+\frac{|\vec{k}|^2}{(1-u^2)}\right)G(u)$$
this is basically a Laplacian and I would like to obtain $G(u)$ for arbitrary $k$ (at least 50, in practice).

```
myInf = 1;
eq1[G_Symbol, u_, k_,uP_] := (2 u*G'[u] - (1 - u^2) G''[u]) + (k^2) G[u]/(1 - u^2) == DiracDelta[u - uP];
sol[uP_, k_, tol_, vv_] := NDSolve[Evaluate[{eq1[gg, u, k, uP], gg[-myInf + tol] == 0, gg'[-myInf + tol] == vv}], gg, {u, -myInf + tol, myInf - tol}];
greenSol[uP_, k_, tol_, vv_?NumericQ] := gg[u] /. Evaluate[sol[uP, k, tol, vv]][[1]] /. u -> myInf - tol;
```

Example of good result:

```
initD = vv /. FindRoot[Evaluate[greenSol[2/5, 2, 0.01`30, vv]], {vv, 0.1},  WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
Plot[Evaluate[gg[u] /. sol[2/5, 2, 0.01`30, initD]], {u, -myInf + .01,  myInf - .01}, PlotRange -> {{-myInf, myInf}, Automatic}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]]
```

Comment: I'm afraid that even with your detailed description, it is hard to give a definitive answer. Would it be possible that you provide a synthetic example that shows the same behavior and that can be posted as code here?

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Oh I see, I will produce a simple version shortly.

Comment: The equation in the question can be solved symbolically.  Are you attempting to obtain a good procedure for obtaining it numerically as well?

Comment: Yes I know, I removed a lot more stuff from the actual system. So that we focus on the problematic part, so yes I would like a numerical procedure which I can later adapt.

Comment: Derive the Green's Function in symbolic form and plot it, and you will see why obtaining it numerically will be difficult for large `k`.  It becomes a highly localized function as `k` is increased.  Precision loss, for instance, could become a serious problem.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion bbgodfrey, I have seen how the solution should look like, however that is exactly why I am asking for tips or tricks to handle this precision loss.

Comment: I believe that I can solve this problem numerically but not for a few days.  Would yo9u still be interested?

Comment: By all means :) If you could point towards any reference or direction which I can check myself, that would also be of much use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the homogeneous ODE is singular at its endpoints, begin by determining the asymptotic solution at one of them, here `u == 1`.

```
eq = 2 u*G'[u] - (1 - u^2) G''[u] + k^2 G[u]/(1 - u^2);
AsymptoticDSolveValue[eq == 0, G, {u, 1, 1}]
(* (1 - ((k/4 + k^2/4) (-1 + u))/(1 + k/2 + 1/2 (1 + k/2) k - k^2/4)) 
       (-1 + u)^(k/2) C[1] 
 + (1 - ((-(k/4) + k^2/4) (-1 + u))/(1 - k/2 - 1/2 (1 - k/2) k - k^2/4)) 
       (-1 + u)^(-k/2) C[2] *)
```

The solution proportional to `C[1]` satisfies `G[1] == 0`.  However, its first `k/2 - 1` derivatives also vanish at the boundary, which causes `NDSolve` problems for large `k`.  It is convenient, therefore, to define a new function, `g[u] == G[u]/(1 - u)^(k/2)`, which is better behaved there, and solve it numerically (here with `uP == 1/2` and `k == 50`.

```
eqp = Simplify[(1 - u)^(-k/2) eq /. G -> Function[u, g[u] (1 - u)^(k/2)]];
stp = NDSolveValue[{eqp == 0, g[1 - 10^-5] == 1, g'[1 - 10^-5] == 0} /. k -> 50, 
    g, {u, 1/2, 1 - 10^-5}, WorkingPrecision -> 30];
```

Now, do the same at `u == -1`.

```
AsymptoticDSolveValue[eq == 0, G, {u, -1, 1}]
(* (1 + u)^(k/2) (1 - ((-(k/4) - k^2/4) (1 + u))/
       (1 + k/2 + 1/2 (1 + k/2) k - k^2/4)) C[1] 
 + (1 + u)^(-k/2) (1 - ((k/4 - k^2/4) (1 + u))/
       (1 - k/2 - 1/2 (1 - k/2) k - k^2/4)) C[2] *)
```

which indicates that here the auxiliary function should be `g[u] == G[u]/(1 + u)^(k/2)`.

```
eqm = Simplify[(1 + u)^(-k/2) eq /. G -> Function[u, g[u] (1 + u)^(k/2)]];
stm = NDSolveValue[{eqm == 0, g[-1 + 10^-5] == 1, g'[-1 + 10^-5] == 0} /. k -> 50, 
    g, {u, -1 + 10^-5, 1/2}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

To create the corresponding Green's Function at `uP == 1/2`, match `stp[u] (1 - u)^(k/2)` and `stm[u] (1 + u)^(k/2)` and their first derivatives there.

```
0 == (dp stp[u] (1 - u)^(k/2) - dm stm[u] (1 + u)^(k/2)) /. {u -> 1/2, k -> 50};
-1/(1 - u^2) == D[dp stp[u] (1 - u)^(k/2) - dm stm[u] (1 + u)^(k/2), u] 
    /. {u -> 1/2, k -> 50};
sd = Solve[{%, %%}, {dm, dp}] // Flatten;
```

The Green's Function at `uP == 1/2` then  is

```
gf[u_] = Piecewise[{{dm (1 + u)^(k/2) stm[u], u < 1/2}, 
    {dp (1 - u)^(k/2) stp[u], u >= 1/2}}] /. sd /. k -> 50;

Plot[gf[u], {u, -1 + 10^-5, 1 - 10^-5}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {u, G}]
```

[image]

The peak value,

```
gf[1/2]
(* 0.00999999999999999817834769562 *)
```

compares favorably with the analytical value of `1/100`.  To see how extreme the variation of `gf` is, consider

```
gf[1 - 10^-5]
(* 2.52543880312194881294211586*10^-123 *)
```

It is no wonder that `NDSolve` has great difficulty with the original equation.  Incidentally, the symbolic Green's Function can be derived without difficulty (although not with `GreenFunction`, unfortunately).  When plotted, it matches well the solution determined numerically here.

**Addendum: What to do if `AsymptoticNDSolve` unavailable.**

In response to a comment below, the auxiliary function also can be obtained using `Series` as follows.  For `u == 1` replace `G[u]` by the trial auxiliary function, `f[u] (1 - u)^n`, and expand `eq` about `u == 1`.

```
Series[(eq /. G -> Function[u, f[u] (1 - u)^n]) (1 - u)^-n, {u, 1, -1}]
(* SeriesData[u, 1, {Rational[-1, 2] k^2 f[1] + 2 n^2 f[1]}, -1, 0, 1] *)
```

This term needs to vanish, which provides the desired value for `n`.

```
SeriesCoefficient[%, -1];
Solve[% == 0, n] // Flatten
(* {n -> -(k/2), n -> k/2} *)
```

Select the positive solution and proceed as above.

Comment: Hi bbgodfrey, it happens to be the case that the AsymptoticDSolveValue is only available from version 11.3 onwards. Do you know of any alternatives in previous versions?

Comment: @ohneVal  Good question.  Please see the material I just added as an addendum.